# Animation with clip:rect

Tags: css, animation, webkit, clip, rect

a have to animate an image with a ray of light. i do it in the following way:

```
.lightLong {
    -webkit-animation-name: lightLong;
    animation-name: lightLong;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-duration: 2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes lightLong {
    0% {
        clip: rect(0px 1162px 64px 1094px);
    }
    100% {
        clip: rect(0px 1162px 481px 0px);
    }
}


@keyframes lightLong {
    0% {
        clip: rect(0px 1162px 64px 1094px);
    }
    100% {
        clip: rect(0px 1162px 481px 0px);
    }
}
```

and that's what happens: 
[what happens with image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nqpl3.jpg)
what can be done to avoid the angle in animation and it was like a ray of light? 
may impose some mask or something like that?
here is example: http://jsbin.com/wamoyereya/edit?html,css,output
thank you!

Comment: You mean something like [this](http://jsbin.com/patomubumi/1/edit?css,output)?

Comment: @Harry , no, it must be as this. http://clip2net.com/s/3sdFJve . with an opacity in the end) such as ray of light